# Angular Filter Date to Show Four Digit Hour Field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

I am trying to filter a Date() field to show four digits when it comes to the hours. Below code does not work. What can I do to have the following format: `HHHH:mm:ss`

```
app.filter('secondsToHHmmss', function($filter) {
    return function(seconds) {
        return $filter('date')(new Date(0, 0, 0, 0).setSeconds(seconds), 'HHHH:mm:ss');
    };
})
```

I could settle for `dd:hh:mm:ss` format, but the problem is that whenever I initialize a zero value Date() object, the days are always shown equal to 31. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: would help to know what input is.

Comment: Input is a difference of two Date objects. I am always measuring the difference and adding it to the total.

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

Try `00:hh:mm:ss` or `00HHmmss`.

### Explanation

`HHHH` is not a valid hour format, so Angular won't parse it correctly. There are four valid hour formats:

1. `HH`: Hour in day, padded (00-23)
2. `H`: Hour in day (0-23)
3. `hh`: Hour in AM/PM, padded (01-12)
4. `h`: Hour in AM/PM, (1-12)

(*Source: [https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date_)*)

Setting a "zero value date" with the expression `new Date(0, 0, 0, 0)` will always return a Javascript date of `Sun Dec 31 1899 00:00:00` plus your local timezone offset and TZID abbreviation, which is why you're seeing the Angular filter return a date of `31`.

If you're just trying to put placeholder characters in the first two digits of your return value, you can do that directly in your formatter, e.g. `00:hh:mm:ss` or `00HHmmss`.

Comment: What if I wanted to count the days as well?

Comment: That is, I would like to count the days, but I want them to start from zero if `hours < 24`

Comment: @MadPhysicist the math isn't complicated. Don't see how using date filter would even be of any use for that

Comment: @MadPhysicist well it boils down to using the right tool for the job